# Regex for matching special alphanumeric patterns with zeros

Tags: regex

I have created a regex to match if a string contains all 'zeroes.' 'All-zeroes' are not allowed in the input box. I have been able to achieve this requirement, however it is a `hard-coded` one.

The regex I have written is as follows:

```
(^[a-zA-Z](?!(0000000|000000\b|00000\b|0000\b|000\b|00\b|0\b))[0-9]{1,7}$)
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your current pattern is achieving what you want, you can simplify it by using negative lookahead for `0+$`, ensuring that the first character is not followed by *only* zeros:

```
^[a-zA-Z](?!0+$)[0-9]{1,7}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/neOfJm/1

Answer (score 1):

You could also use groups `()` with <kbd>|</kbd> and create match for your pattern, maybe similar to [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/vMFKOU/1):

```
^[A-Za-z](([1-9]+)|(0+[1-9]))$
```

[image]

And you might bound it with other boundaries, such as the number of chars for <kbd>numbers</kbd> or <kbd>alpha</kbd>.